# Unlocking boot loader **doesn't** wipe data. How is it a security threat?

Tags: security, bootloader, mi-a1

MiA1 is probably the only one of it's kind that **doesn't** wipe data when bootloader is unlocked (tested by me and widely known)

It is said to be a security threat. **I am not clear how**

Say my device is stolen and one wants to access data how does this feature make it easier given

- I use 6 digit PIN and fingerprint. One has to get past that before `adb` can be activated and  used to transfer data to a PC.
- The device is encrypted (Oreo 8.0.0)
- Debugging turned off

(I am not  talking of risks of unlocked boot loader. I understand that)

This is not a hypothetical question but something I need to understand, this being my daily use device.

I don't have information that calls for three letter agencies to use sophisticated tools , so that angle can be ruled out while answering (though useful to know).

I am looking for realistic threat assessment

Comment: As soon as they can flash a custom recovery with fastboot, the device is essentially completely theirs, including all of that data. Encrypting the device  will stop them being able to access that data unless they know the password to decrypt it though.

Comment: @Sonickyle27: you are right but the device is encrypted. Added that to question. Thanks

Comment: @Sonickyle27 also what you say is possible for any other device which has unlocked boot loader already

Comment: And what if they can decrypt those data without your password, say they have tools that break this encryption?

Comment: @esQmo_ that's why the last paragraph - is not with the effort :)

Comment: With the custom recovery a root shell can be invoked and then USB debugging can be enabled. As far as encryption it depends on the level of security type and where the key is stored. If a key is stored on-device it does not protect the application data from root users. The key has to be eventually provided to an app and thus be vulnerable.

Comment: @BoLawson : Standard OS encryption (Oreo) and the key I suppose is in the RAM and I have read about methods that dump RAM for key extraction - last paragraph rules out sophisticated methods of this kind

Comment: As a side note, I was able to unlock the bootloader of my P880 back then without wiping as well, as someone on XDA came up with a specific method – so yours is not the only one. But so far I haven't heard of many devices falling into this category (only our two and I vaguely remember a third one).

Answer (score 1):

Using `twrp decrypt password` one can easily write a simple brute force script to guess your password. And as I can see it, there isn't any limit on how many times this command can be executed, so depending on the strength of your password, your device will be unlocked one day or the other.

Having debugging turned off doesn't make any difference in TWRP

Comment: Theoretically possible but vague in terms of how much time it would take. Need figures to substantiate what you are saying. In the meantime, what's stopping me from wiping my data using Google account?

Comment: Also your answer in the present form is speculative. Nothing to show how it can be done as you suggest or proof that it is tried and tested

Comment: @beeshyams time is very relative to your setup, but definitely nothing too huge. Take a look at [this article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/). And the device can be kept switched off for the entire process, wiping using your Google account won't do anything. And what I said is the simplest hacking technique, doesn't require any 'proof of concept' in this day and age. Like the article I linked above, millions of people try this everyday.

Comment: In case you didn't know, ***the fappening*** was a result of a similar attack I posted as my answer. So its a tried and tested method in the wild.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It still is a special set up which is required. Please read again the last two paragraphs. I am looking for how I am at risk in the absence of such tools. Next, if the password were to be cracked this way, any device is at risk equally isn't it? But yes , your point of Google wipe is pertinent

Comment: @beeshyams this is not a special NSA level hack. Its barely 10 lines of code any noobie could write. And no, only your particular model is at risk. Because any normal device would wipe it's internal memory when I unlock bootloader and install TWRP on it. On your device it doesn't, so your data isn't safe when you lose your device.